# Is there any possibility of having same serial number for two IPads

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm

While scanning DeviceInformation via IOs MDM protocol it is seen that one of the customers two IPads are giving same serial numbers. DeviceInformation MDM command response contains all values like

Model,DeviceName,BluetoothMAC,OSVersion,UDID,AvailableDeviceCapacity,EASDeviceIdentifier

are different but 
**SerialNumber is same.** 
Both are IPads with 'OSVersion': '10.3.3' and 'OSVersion': '10.2'

Is it an issue from apple side.

Due to security reasons, I cannot expose the DeviceInformation MDM command response.

Comment: Type the number into [Apple's warranty web site](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/us/en) and see how much warranty is left. I strongly suspect that Apple wouldn't even recognize this serial number, because these are not genuine devices manufactured by Apple.

Comment: I checked it and warranty is left with the device.

Comment: That's odd. Usually only clones have identical serial numbers.

Comment: It's strange, With the help of customer we figured out things as follows.
The other device is not owned by the customer and the duplicate device is located somewhere in China
and both devices are enrolled via DEP.